# Calling an On-Premise API with Microsoft Bot

Tags: botframework

I'm looking to create a Bot which will accept messages/converstations from Microsoft Teams and submit them via an API to our on-preimse helpdesk tool to either update tickets or return results to the user.

If the Bot is hosted in Azure with a firewall preventing communication to the on-premise API, how to enable connectivity between the two without using a tunneling service such a ngrok.

Opening the firewall is a last restort, but is there any other method.
We use On-Premise Data Gateway for PowerBI, is it possible for bots to connect via the gateway?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. The tag you have used has nothing to do with chat bots (RobotFramework is a functional test automation framework). Moreover, your question is too broad and not related to programming. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you can elaborate your question a bit more with some research and tests, that might be a candidate for more dedicated sites like https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

I think the firewall (depending on how it is set up of course) would block both something like ngrok and a gateway tool (though I'm not familiar with the PowerBI tool). You could create a static IP for your bot application and only allow that IP access to your on-prem API.